# Finding the integral $\int \sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to find the integral $$\displaystyle\int \sqrt{1-\dfrac{3}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}\mathrm dx$$ ?

I cannot think of any suitable method. I tried trigonometric substitutions but they were of no use. Hints please!

Comment: HAve you tried $\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2-3x+1}}{x}\,dx$?

Comment: @TitoEliatron Isn't that the same thing? What should I try with it ?

Comment: Yeah!

$x^2-3x+1=(x-3/2)^2-5/4$ and you can use the C.V. $x-3/2=\sqrt5/2 \sec t$
or $\sqrt{x^2-3x+1}=x+t$

Comment: @TitoEliatron I used the first substitution and I'm getting $$\int \frac{\tan(t)}{\sec(t)+\frac{3}{\sqrt(5)}}\sec(t)\tan(t)dt$$ What to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Euler substitution of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#The_first_substitution_of_Euler), let $\sqrt{x^2-3x+1}=x+t$,we have
\begin{align*}
\int{\frac{\sqrt{x^2-3x+1}}{x}}\text{d}x&=-2\int{\frac{\left( t^2+3t+1 \right) ^2}{\left( 1-t^2 \right) \left( 2t+3 \right) ^2}}\text{d}t \\
&=-2\int\left (  \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{2t+3}-\frac{5}{4}\frac{1}{\left (  2t+3\right )^{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{4}\right ) \mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}
then you can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts to break up the integral
\begin{align}
&\int \sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}} \, dx\\
=& \ x \sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}
+\int \frac1{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx
-\frac32 \int \frac1{x\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx
\end{align}
and then apply the Euler substitution $\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}=t-\frac1x$ to evaluate
\begin{align}
&\int \frac1{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx 
=\int\frac2{3-2t}dt = -\ln|3-2t|\\
&\int \frac1{x\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}}dx 
=\int\frac2{1-t^2}dt = -\ln |\frac{t-1}{t+1}|\\
\end{align}